# Create a pod file in Mac OS X v10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-workspace, podfile

How ca I create a pod file in [Mac OS X v10.11.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan)?

What do I use instead of "sudo gem install cocoa pods" and "pod setup --verbose"?

Comment: correct command is `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

Create a pod file:

```
touch podfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

This helped.